# How to solve problem with repetitive displaying datas in pretty Tables Python

Tags: python, sqlite, console

I created database with SQLite3 in python console. In main menu I've got option "Display all data". I used pretty table in python. But the problem is when I don't exit program and I choose 3 times the same option "Display all data" it adds all rows every time I choose this option. Lets assume I've got 4 rows in database and every time I choose "Display all data" it displays/adds next 4 rows to table.The code below

```
import sqlite3 as sql
from prettytable import PrettyTable
  x = PrettyTable()

def display_all_data():
    conn = sql.connect("register.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT firstname,lastname,date_of_birth,id_number FROM datas ORDER BY lastname")
    rec = cur.fetchall()
    x.field_names = ["Firstname", "Lastname", "Date of Birth", "ID number"]
    for item in rec:
        print([x.add_row([rec[1],rec[2],rec[3],rec[4]]))

    #outside the for-loop

    print(x)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Every time I choose function display_all_datas it add the same 4 rows but Every time when I choose this option I want to display the rows once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```py
for item in rec:
    print([x.add_row([rec[1],rec[2],rec[3],rec[4]])
```

to:

```py
for item in rec:
    print([x.add_row(item)])
```

However, if you want that each call to `display_all_data` should add only one row, then you need to reformat a bit of your code. You'll need to create the `conn` and execute the query outside the function, and then use `cur.fetchone()` in the function.

```py
import sqlite3 as sql
from prettytable import PrettyTable
x = PrettyTable()
conn = sql.connect("register.db")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT firstname,lastname,date_of_birth,id_number FROM datas ORDER BY lastname")
x.field_names = ["Firstname", "Lastname", "Date of Birth", "ID number"]
    
def display_one_line_of_data():
    rec = cur.fetchone()
    print([x.add_row(rec))

    #outside the for-loop

    print(x)
```

Comment: Great it displays once but above the table it displays 4 times verticaly None

Comment: It displays again several times

Comment: Are you calling `display_all_data` multiple times? But ideally, you want it to display one row only?

Comment: Yes Let's assume I want to choose several times this option and every time it displays more times these rows